unable to setup drizzle in express
This is how drizzle tells to setup db connection with mysql. I am using express and top level await without async, i dont understand how this works?
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/mysql2";
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
  host: "host",
  user: "user",
  database: "database",
  ...
});

const db = drizzle(connection);

I changed the code above to
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/mysql2";
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";
import * as schema from "./schema";

let connection: mysql.Connection;

(async () => {
  connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    multipleStatements: true,
  });
})();

export const db = drizzle(connection, { schema: schema, mode: "default" });

but now i am getting an error Variable 'connection' is used before being assigned
I am unable to get it to work. What am I missing?

I have posted my answer. Please check and let me know.

Either you use Non-null assertion operator
let connection!: mysql.Connection;

or You can do this...
let connection: mysql.Connection | null = null;

I hope it will resolve this issue Variable 'connection' is used before being assigned.
If you still face any issue then let me know.
